# Bootstrap Button CSS changes not working for :active selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap 3.3.7 button, and want the button to stay the same color when a mouse focuses, hovers, or clicks on it.

```
<button class="btn btn-default delete-btn">Delete</button>
```

Here is where I modify the background-color for my CSS selectors:

```
.delete-btn:hover, .delete-btn:focus, .delete-btn:active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

This works just fine for a focus or hover event.

However, when the mouse clicks on the button, it changes to it's default grey color. Any ideas what I am missing here? Scratching my head...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap stylesheet has this set of selectors:

```
.btn-default.active.focus, .btn-default.active:focus, .btn-default.active:hover, .btn-default:active.focus, .btn-default:active:focus, .btn-default:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover
```

`.btn-default:active:focus` and `.btn-default:active:hover` are more specific than selectors with only one pseudo-class.

You need to make your selector equally specific:

```
.delete-btn:hover, .delete-btn:focus,
.delete-btn:active:hover, .delete-btn:active:focus, {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the selector .btn.btn-default.delete-btn instread of only .delete-btn and use important.

```
.btn.btn-default.delete-btn:hover, .btn.btn-default.delete-btn:focus, .btn.btn-default.delete-btn:active {
     background-color: white !important;
}
```

Else, Inspect element on your browser to find the grey color and replace the whole css rule with white color.

Else, check if there is something wrong going on in your javascript and replace your color rule with click event.

Answer (score -1):

Try add important at the end of code like this:`background-color: white!important;` .

Answer (score -1):

Add !important after your css attributes which replace bootstrap default css with yours and give priority to your css For avoiding box shadow use box-shadow. Add This Css:---

```
.delete-btn:hover, .delete-btn:focus, .delete-btn:active {
                background-color: white !important;
                box-shadow: none !important;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

use !important in your styles to replace default styles of bootstrap